# Using AVAudioPlayer vs SKAction.playSoundFileNamed in SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

If I use AVAudioPlayer to play a sound effect instead of the SpriteKit way `SKAction.playSoundFileNamed`, will there be any performance or other issues related?

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286767/openal-vs-avaudioplayer-vs-other-techniques-for-playing-sounds